# How can I save the current layout of a SchedulerControl as the default layout upon closing the form in DevExpress using VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

The user can change the timeline and view of the SchedulerControl. I want the layout to be set as the default layout upon closing the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can save and restore the Scheduler Control's layout as detailed in the [How to: Save and Restore a Layout](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2264/controls-and-libraries/scheduler/examples/layout/how-to-save-and-restore-a-layout) documentation.

The Scheduler Control offers three different methods for saving a layout, which you can invoke when the form is closed:

- [SaveLayoutToRegistry](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraScheduler.SchedulerControl.SaveLayoutToRegistry(System.String))
- [SaveLayoutToStream](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraScheduler.SchedulerControl.SaveLayoutToStream(System.IO.Stream))
- [SaveLayoutToXml](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraScheduler.SchedulerControl.SaveLayoutToXml(System.String))

And each has their own respective version for restoring the layout from the selected store:

- [RestoreLayoutFromRegistry](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraScheduler.SchedulerControl.RestoreLayoutFromRegistry(System.String))
- [RestoryLayoutFromStream](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraScheduler.SchedulerControl.RestoreLayoutFromStream(System.IO.Stream))
- [RestoreLayoutFromXml](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraScheduler.SchedulerControl.RestoreLayoutFromXml(System.String))